# how to make a div floating fixed on the after scrolling to a point

Tags: css

this is the example, the left Nav div can float on the top once hitting to a point when scrolling down

http://www.codecademy.com/glossary/html#attributes_class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into WayPoints jQuery plugin... I use it, and it does very nice things!

http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Once you hit the div that reflects the glossary, you could make jquery search for the 'selected' link, remove the link class from it, and set the class to the new link.  It would take a little time to make it work perfectly, but would do great.